# How to pass parameter by reference to the proc?

Tags: tcl, pass-by-reference

Is there any solid way to pass parameter to `proc` by reference(without using `upvar`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***No.*** Not if you want to be able to modify the value inside the procedure and have that modification visible outside.

Tcl's procedures have their arguments passed *strictly* by value (the implementation actually passes by *immutable* reference, which is cheaper for complex structures, and uses a copy-on-write modification technique under the covers; it looks like pass-by-value) so you can't affect the outside world except by bringing it in with something like `upvar`. Sometimes, the things you pass in might be a handle to a modifiable entry (e.g., a class instance, a DOM node) and then you'd be able to observe a difference from outside, but that's not actually modifying the thing that was passed in itself (the handle) but rather the thing that it references.